# How to dynamicly create data.frames, with dynamic names, in a loop, that are part of a list

Tags: r

I´m writing a function, that should cut out biometric data, after an event happens and add them to a list. 
The cutout part works fine. But the part where I want to add the new data.frames to the list doesn´t.

The code below, is my current state. It creates dynamic list elements, but only adds the data of the first cell to each list element.

```
Event_search <- function(a,b,c){ # a = Data, b = Eventmarker, c = time to cut
  Return = list();
  x =nrow(b);   #Number of events
  for(i in 1:x){
    Start = b[i,7];   #Getting the time for an event
    Stop = Start + c; #Caluculating the endtime for an event based extraction
    Event_Data = data.frame();
    Event_Data <- a[ which(a[,7]>=Start & a[,7] <=Stop), ]; #writing the extrated data in a data.frame
    Return[paste("Event", i , sep="_")] <- Event_Data;  #this one creates 
  };
  return(Return);
}
```

This code also creates the warning: `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

If I add the data.frame names manually by changing:

`Return[paste("Event", i , sep="_")] <- Event_Data;`
to
`Return$Event <- Event_Data;`

It add´s the whole data.frame, but unfortunatly that solution wouldn`t be dynamic.

So my question is, how can I create dynamic list elements, that are capable to hold a whole dataframe.

Comment: Use double brackets: `Return[[paste("Event", i , sep="_")]] <- Event_Data`

Comment: Thank you very much.
This did the job.

Comment: If you haven't yet, you should take some time and study `help("[")`.

Answer (score 0):

[Rolands](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland) comment did the job.

`Use double brackets: Return[[paste("Event", i , sep="_")]] <- Event_Data`